# How do extract the string before the colon?

Tags: regex, perl

How do extract the string before the colon. I don't want the string after the colon.

Sample input:

```
asfmqwdbd/ilcp:dftqclk_rep
```

Desired result:

```
asfmqwdbd/ilcp
```

My code:

```
if (m/^(\S+))
  $inst_name = $1;
```

Comment: `m/^([^\s:]+)/` - if you meant *before the first **colon***

Comment: Can ypu please edit your question? Your example does not contain a semicolon `;`. Did you mean colon `:`?

Comment: Shouldn't the desired result be `asfmqwdbd/ilcp`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that semicolon (`;`) was a typo in the question and you actually meant colon (`:`) this would be the correct regex:

- anchor at beginning of line (`^`)
- capture one-or-more non-colon characters (`([^:]+)`)
- match must end on a colon (`:`)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    print "$1\n" if /^([^:]+):/;
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
asfmqwdbd/ilcp
asfmqwdbd/ilcp:dftqclk_repasfmq
asfmqwdbd/ilcp;dftqclk_repasfmq
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
asfmqwdbd/ilcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your question you want the output like this
"asfmqwdbd/ilcp"
for this you can use "^([\S]+):" and then use $1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
$ echo "asfmqwdbd/ilcp:dftqclk_repasfmq" | perl -pe 's/(\S+):.*/$1/ '
asfmqwdbd/ilcp
```

or

```
$ perl -le ' $x="asfmqwdbd/ilcp:dftqclk_repasfmq"; $x=~s/(\S+):.*/$1/; print $x '
asfmqwdbd/ilcp

$
```